# Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, bigint, 128-bit, int128

I want a 128 bit integer because I want to store results of multiplication of two 64 bit numbers. Is there any such thing in gcc 4.4 and above?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329541/does-gcc-support-128-bit-int-on-amd64

Comment: @chux: Why did you reopen this?  The top answer here is wrong, claiming that `uint128_t` is defined when in fact gcc provides `unsigned __int128` or `__uint128_t`.  And currently only on 64-bit targets where 128-bit only takes 2 integer registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes I VTO as the 2 dupes listed did not answer the question.  My VTO was not related to any answers.

Comment: @chux: ok that's fair, but wasn't it closed as a dup of [Does gcc support 128-bit int on amd64?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3329541)?  That looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes This question was closed due to 2 dupes:  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329541) was narrower and so not a dupe of this question - and another.  That [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329615/2410359) addresses gcc in general 4.6 and before, but not this question's about 4.4 onward. Certainly these and many other relates questions are similar   and on the border of being sufficiently similar/different

Comment: @chux: This question says "or above", and gcc4.6 is pretty old at this point.  (Although admittedly I have seen answers this year with asm output from gcc4.4 on RHEL).  Anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16088282/timeline doesn't show the other (not?) duplicate that this was closed as.  The comments were are auto-deleted when the dup close went through, and the close even itself doesn't seem to have recorded the duplicate list.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

For GCC before C23, a primitive 128-bit integer type is **only ever available on 64-bit targets**, so you need to check for availability even if you have already detected a recent GCC version.  In theory gcc *could* support TImode integers on machines where it would take 4x 32-bit registers to hold one, but I don't think there are any cases where it does.

In C++, consider a library such as  [`boost::multiprecision::int128_t`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html), but it doesn't use compiler-specific wide types, [always sign/magnitude](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) (with a 128-bit magnitude plus a separate sign bit, so a wider value-range than 128-bit 2's complement).  You might want an `#ifdef` to typedef GCC's `__int128` or Clang's `_BitInt(128)` on systems that have that, only typedef to Boost as a fallback, if your use-case is ok with a wider value-range.  See also [@phuclv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261291/an-efficient-way-to-do-basic-128-bit-integer-calculations-in-c/28117872#28117872) on another question.

**ISO C23 will let you `typedef unsigned _BitInt(128)  u128`**, modeled on [clang's feature](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types) originally called `_ExtInt()`  which works even on 32-bit machines; see [a brief intro to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411865/how-do-you-use-clangs-new-custom-size-int-feature). GCC13 `-std=gnu2x` doesn't even support that syntax yet, but current nightly GCC14 trunk does support it with `-std=gnu23` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nxvqrEqx1))

---

**GCC 4.6 and later has a `__int128` / `unsigned __int128` defined as a built-in type.**  Use
**`#ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__`** to detect it.

**GCC 4.1 and later define `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` as built-in types**.  (You don't need `#include <stdint.h>` for these, either.  Proof [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29EAGYAbOR2YAMgXrYAcqYBG2UsIAO6JcSa9AbGZpY2fgEaDI7Obiae3tzKqtjqQUxErKREIabm1ilq0fSZ2USxrh5ewkpZOXlhhXXllfGJPACUyuhGpKhcAOQA%2BsNGTkTc0gAcw0QA1HToEBPzAB6d85IA7LLzpNhEffTrkhby2wAig93sIIMArIPk5oMADM/o93oKCvNKvX62C20gs3GeRHuH063QA1pZpAA6B5WN5vB4ATj40jRNjug14zxMCMROO40wsvGmVlB0weFmkLyhn3uzyUIDe5Eh7xu5DgsBQGBMPgInAoVAgQpFYpAwF4U3INFFRC87Ig7mZ5HcTmyAE97uDyEKTDoiAB5ejsfU88g4ExiYCcTWEA7pABu2HZNuwazSRhVBueE1UmvYBHcpD1Bhwga5pAIxMG4O6dEYLA4XD4gmEonEaF%2BchE4fZkG66B8JS9AFozRY2al0loIHZGuZknY2tUkuRIoEGK3fP4%2B/ROwkaskVMUMvVcoZ8rUGyUyjlRx0JzOB%2BvWk4qmOkt0AX0Bl0RPcnkybV9BmtqVWrLx5sBUKh5rxEdxSfMIPhiGQQWDyHmAxhVFLx/24TYfjkBQIWZGFyCQbBWBwbwIFue5CXIYkrG2RFtgxaZuCsB5uAsbYrD4HCLw%2BcgrzZDkuTguESRRNFMWxXFT0GOtqJZQZYJ5bp%2BWQNB0BAsVKGoKVQO8YAMUZJV2BVUg1Q1G1tXoPVY2NU0LStZ1sHtcQnRtF00g0D0vRon0/QDJMg0YEMbTDCMoywIZDSIeNE2TRUGGYNgnSzIQLBEB182gwsXJLNDaIrIJq1respybFs5zCBUOx3doan4XsSk3Rl8qCVdcqKczp3KQrysbUoZ1K7x%2BBaBp0rbRlmoqbKuxAXgD0BY8IK489Xhoq8bysO8HyfF8MU/b9CBIUhwMA4DpTAmQLAsSCC1kAToWYiwHjwh5pjeCxpmkKwMQxCx5P4fFMOJbg0V42jWWUBjuWhPlEAgQUxLW8UpIBmS0FzOSXsU5TVM1DStPso0xJNRg9OtGi7QdEz0YIV0LM9TUbNQf0PIclV8RolzI1IXVoxJuME0DFN/PTIL%2BCERlwYi%2BQouLeAy3ihhEoseYq3tfokDOS4lFhXVRFhbBkoq1LdE3WxdAawcoiCVXipiLq9wXFK6qq1rDaV42V31tdlA3U2t0tuJusGw8gRPfFhs1Mbb3veZUHB%2BZZreRE3i/H9FuWoCQbFf9pG2yLdsYwTukQ5Cali%2BEwURKxCIxN5pBO06Hl4bZyK4zCRr4%2BjOS%2Bm50MGaQiR4F6K7e/jE/28gPRUoIeqAA%3D%3D).)

I tested [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+uint128_t+__uint128_t%0A//%23define+uint128_t+unsigned+__int128%0A%0Auint128_t+mul64(uint64_t+a,+uint64_t+b)+%7B%0A++++return+(uint128_t)a+*+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23ifdef+__SIZEOF_INT128__%0Aint+detected_ok()%7Breturn+1%3B%7D%0A%23endif%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.32694763729248,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g412,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27167%27)),options:%27-xc+-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+4.1.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.3397190293742,l:%274%27,m:56.14564870956661,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc1301,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27167%27)),options:%27-xc+-O3+-xHOST%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+icc+13.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:43.8543512904334,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.3397190293742,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang30,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27167%27)),options:%27-xc+-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+3.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for the first versions of compilers to support each of these 3 things (on x86-64).  Godbolt only goes back to gcc4.1, ICC13, and clang3.0, so I've used <= 4.1 to indicate that the actual first support might have been even earlier.

```
         legacy               recommended(?)    |  One way of detecting support
        __uint128_t   |  [unsigned]  __int128   |  #ifdef __SIZEOF_INT128__
gcc        <=  4.1    |       4.6               |     4.6
clang      <=  3.0    |       3.1               |     3.3
ICC        <=  13     |     <= 13               |     16.  (Godbolt doesn't have 14 or 15)
```

**If you compile for a 32-bit architecture like ARM, or x86 with `-m32`, no 128-bit integer type is supported with even the newest version of any of these  compilers.**  So you *need* to detect support before using, if it's possible for your code to work at all without it.

The only direct CPP macro I'm aware of for detecting it is `__SIZEOF_INT128__`, but unfortunately some old compiler versions support it without defining it.  (And there's no macro for `__uint128_t`, only the gcc4.6 style `unsigned __int128`).  [How to know if __uint128_t is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531782/how-to-know-if-uint128-t-is-defined)

Some people still use ancient compiler versions like gcc4.4 on RHEL (RedHat Enterprise Linux), or similar crusty old systems.  If you care about obsolete gcc versions like that, you probably want to stick to `__uint128_t`.  And maybe detect 64-bitness in terms of `sizeof(void*) == 8` as a fallback for `__SIZEOF_INT128__` no being defined.  (I think GNU systems always have `CHAR_BIT==8`, although I might be wrong about some DSPs).  That will give a false negative on ILP32 ABIs on 64-bit ISAs (like x86-64 Linux x32, or AArch64 ILP32), but this is already just a fallback / bonus for people using old compilers that don't define `__SIZEOF_INT128__`.

There might be some 64-bit ISAs where gcc doesn't define `__int128`, or maybe even some 32-bit ISAs where gcc *does* define `__int128`, but I'm not aware of any.

---

The GCC internals are integer TI mode ([GCC internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Modes.html#index-TImode)).  (Tetra-integer = 4x width of a 32-bit `int`, vs. DImode = double width vs. SImode = plain `int`.)  As [the GCC manual points out](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), `__int128` is supported on targets that support a 128-bit integer mode (TImode).

```
// __uint128_t is pre-defined equivalently to this
typedef unsigned uint128 __attribute__ ((mode (TI)));
```

There is an OImode in the manual, oct-int = 32 bytes, but current GCC for x86-64 complains "unable to emulate 'OI'" if you attempt to use it.

---

Random fact: ICC19 and g++/clang++ `-E -dM` define:

```
#define __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __int128
#define __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0 128
```

@MarcGlisse commented *that's the way you tell libstdc++ to handle extra integer types (overload abs, specialize type traits, etc)*

`icpc` defines that even with `-xc` (to compile as C, not C++), while g++ -xc and clang++ -xc don't.  But compiling with actual `icc` (e.g. select C instead of C++ in the Godbolt language dropdown) doesn't define this macro.

---

The test function was:

```
#include <stdint.h>   // for uint64_t

#define uint128_t __uint128_t
//#define uint128_t unsigned __int128

uint128_t mul64(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    return (uint128_t)a * b;
}
```

compilers that support it all compile it efficiently, to

```
    mov       rax, rdi
    mul       rsi
    ret                  # return in RDX:RAX which mul uses implicitly
```

Comment: `unsigned __int128` - full division is the *worst*. Frequently (especially with div / mod arithmetic routines) we know the quotient will fit in a 64-bit result, but the C run-time can't assume it. I wrote a reference 'modexp' (64-bit base, exponent, modulus), using `__int128` ... vs. a version using 64-bit intrinsics, [reciprocal division](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf), etc., for an *18x* speed-up! 3x or 4x are respectable, but remember that there's always call overhead, and the [u]int128 functions can't make the algorithmic assertions that we can!

Comment: @BrettHale: interesting.  gcc's helper function maybe only checks that the upper half is zero instead of (for unsigned) checking that `divisor > high_half_dividend`.

Comment: Fast types aren't a good way to find out about an architecture's bitness. E.g., musl's `{,u}int_fast{16,32}_t`s on x86_64 are 32 bits, glibc's are 64 (also not good to include in an API for that matter).

Comment: @PSkocik: IDK why I even suggested that in the first place.  I think I had been hoping to find something that would even work on ILP32 ABIs like x86-64 Linux's x32, or AArch64 ILP32, but that is not the case.  Glad to hear MUSL makes it 32-bit on x86-64; that makes more sense to me.  I hadn't realized it wasn't nailed down by the ABI and therefore not suitable for use in an API.

Comment: @PeterCordes It caught me by surprise too. I also think 32 bits is probably a better choice. IIRC from the last time I benchmarked this, 32 bit ops gave me pretty much the same numbers (better by a tiny amount) as 64 bit ops.

Comment: @PSkocik: 64-bit integers can sometimes save an instruction for sign-extension when used as array indices, but otherwise are strictly worse.  Large code-size (REX prefixes), and much slower `div` on Intel CPUs (~2.5x).  On AMD before Zen, 64-bit `mul`/`imul` is slower than 32-bit.  Also 64-bit `popcnt` is slower on some CPUs.  (All of these are compared to 32-bit, the default operand-size in x86-64 machine code, which zero-extends to 64-bit for free.)

Comment: About __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0, it isn't just ICC that defines it, that's the way you tell libstdc++ to handle extra integer types (overload abs, specialize type traits, etc).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Turns out passing `-xc` to ICC's C++ front-end doesn't make it preprocess as C or something.  Thanks, updated.

Comment: Good answer, but Boost.Multiprecision does *not* use built-in wide types according to [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) ("things you should know" section), which says that it uses a sign/magnitude representation.

Comment: @Nemo: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 34):

Ah, big integers are not C's forte.

GCC does have an `unsigned __int128`/`__int128` type, starting from version 4.something (not sure here). I do seem to recall, however, that there was a `__int128_t` def before that.

These are only available on 64-bit targets.

(Editor's note: this answer used to claim that gcc defined `uint128_t` and `int128_t`.  None of the versions I tested on the Godbolt compiler explorer define those types without leading `__`, from gcc4.1 to 8.2 , or clang or ICC.)

Comment: `long long int` is 64 bits in every implementation I've used, including GCC for x86-64. And I believe that GCC's 128-bit int is only available on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I just tried it in 2 systems, and they stand by your results. I've removed the assertion of it going up to 128 bits long.

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 on Linux x86_64 doesn't have `[]int128_t`. I suppose it's possible gcc 4.8.0  might have it.

Comment: Try `typedef int really_long __attribute__ ((mode (TI)));`. It has worked for a long time (on architectures with native 64-bit).

Comment: `gcc-4.1 -m64` and above support `__uint128_t` out-of-the-box, and they also support the following typedef: `typedef unsigned uint128_t __attribute__ ((mode (TI)));`.

Comment: GCC had 128-bit int since at least 4.1.2 [Is there any way to do 128 bit ints on gcc <4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5576217/995714#comment90833163_5576526)

Comment: @Peter Cordes Your edit nicely improved this answer.

Comment: Apologies for going somewhat off-topic. Is there some way that we could optionally make use of 128-bit vector registers in eg x86, AMD64 ? I realise that arithmetic could either be awkward or would require temporary copying to/from ordinary integer registers. But the advantages would be getting loads/stores to/from memory to use the native 128-bit instructions, use the full memory bandwidth, and also making use of the vector registers reduces general register pressure so improving unrelated code that would otherwise need spills. Compiler backend needs to evaluate potential gains vs losses.

Comment: I should perhaps have placed my question elsewhere, somewhere more suitable, not sure where.

Answer (score 16):

You could use a library which handles arbitrary or large precision values, such as the [GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Reed gave a perfectly valid answer for non-64-bit machines. This question is the number one response to a search for "C int128", so having a general answer for any platform is a good thing. Maybe next time if you feel so strong about this subject write an answer instead of tearing someone else down (that way you can reap the rep benefits as well).

Comment: @CrazyCasta having an arbitrary-precision library just for a 128-bit type is just too wasteful, and the overhead is just too big. A fixed-width library like [Boost.Multiprecision or calccrypto/uint128_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117872/995714) will be much smaller and faster