# Storing 128 and 256 bit data types (ints and floats) in C without using any data structures (like arrays and others) and external libraries

Tags: c, storage

How can i store **128** or **256** bit data types(ints and floats) without using any data structures(like arrays and others) and external libraries on a 64-bit machine.I am using codeblocks.

Comment: You can't. Not under the conditions you've imposed.

Comment: It might depend on your architecture and compiler.  For gcc on x64, then you can do 128 bit integers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using the C language as laid out in the standard. However, depending on your compiler and architecture, you may have compiler-specific support for larger integer sizes. For instance, GCC supplies limited [support](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html#g_t_005f_005fint128) for 128-bit integers, which you can use like so:

```
__int128 foo; //foo is a 128-bit signed integer.
```

However, the real question is probably why you are so determined not to use a library or basic language features like arrays to implement your own.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can somehow implement it on my own.

Comment: @chanzerre: you can indeed implement it on your own, but you'll need to use arrays in order to do so. I don't imagine it would be too difficult. :-)

Comment: I am trying to implement what you suggested.But gcc doesn't even recognize __int128 and int128_t or uint128_t either.I am using codeblocks on windows platform.

Comment: @chanzerre: Are you sure you're using GCC? If so, you need to be on an architecture which supports it (i.e. 64-bit), and you need to turn off any 'strict C' settings you may have (`-pedantic`, `-ansi`...). It works for me on Linux, x86_64.