# How to store 64 digits integer in C?

Tags: c, warnings, long-long

I am dealing with 2 64 digits integers and need to multiple these two numbers.
When I tried to store it into a `long long int` variable, I got the following compiling error:

> 1.c: In function ‘main’:
>   1.c:5:6: warning: integer constant is too large for its type.
>   a = 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234;

Can someone tell me how to store the integer in C?

[edit] OP later [implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576430/how-to-store-64-digits-integer-in-c/44576521#comment76141782_44576521) a 64 *decimal* digit number.

Comment: Indeed, that number itself is far bigger than 64 bits can hold.

Comment: @KenWhite but a 128-bit number is guaranteed to hold the result

Comment: @KenWhite I even cannot store the 64-bits number into a long long int variable, why is that?

Comment: @Yunnosch KenWhite deleted his comment, which said that "a 64-bit integer would not be able to hold the product of 2 64-bit integers". I'm aware the decimal constant is much bigger than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234` is not a 64-bit number.  It is a 64 *decimal digit* number needing about 210+ *binary* bits to be stored.

Try storing a 64-bit number

```
long long s1 = 9223372036854775807;
long long s2 = -9223372036854775807 - 1;
unsigned long long u1 = 18446744073709551615u;
```

---

To store a 64-digit decimal number in standard C, you need to use another approach as C's integer types are specified for only up to 64 binary digits (bits) although wider ones *could* exist: Store as your own array of digits, as a string, or use a bignum library like [gmp](https://gmplib.org). It depends on what you want to do with that stored 64-decimal digit number.

---

Example string approach.  It lacks buffer protection, nor removes leading zeros and is not so efficient.  It does demonstrate the flow of what is needed - [basic long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication).

```
char *string_mult2(char *product, const char *a, const char *b) {
  size_t alen = strlen(a);
  size_t blen = strlen(b);
  size_t clen = alen + blen;
  memset(product, '0', clen);
  product[clen] = 0;
  for (size_t ai = alen; ai-- > 0;) {
    unsigned acc = 0;
    size_t ci = --clen;
    for (size_t bi = blen; bi-- > 0;) {
      acc += product[ci] - '0' + (a[ai] - '0') * (b[bi] - '0');
      product[ci--] = acc % 10 + '0';
      acc /= 10;
    }
    product[ci] = acc % 10 + '0';
  }
  return product;
}

int main(void) {
  char *a = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
  //a = "12";
  char *b = a;
  char product[200];
  puts(string_mult2(product,a,b));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

After you tried compiling the code and ran it, mouse over the below to see my result.

> 01524157875323883675049535156256668194500838287337600975522511810828928529615005335814711781866792303015211342784374345526722756

Comment: I got it. But in my case, how to store the 64 digits number in C?

Comment: @MarkDong, do you want 64 digits, or 64 bits?

Answer (score 1):

This multiplies two 64-decimal-digit integers using the [GNU multiple precision arithmetic library](https://gmplib.org/)

**example.c**

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // A 64-digit number expressed as a string
  const char str[] = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";

  mpz_t n;                         // mpz_t is the type defined for GMP integers
  mpz_init(n);                     // Initialize the number

  mpz_set_str(n, str, 10);         // parse the string as a base-10 number

  mpz_mul(n, n, n);                // square the number (n = n * n)

  printf("n * n = ");              // print the result
  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);

  return 0;
}
```

**Compile and link with the GMP library**

```
gcc -lgmp example.c -o example
```

**Output**

```
n * n = 15241578753238836750495351562566681945008382873376009755225118122311263526910001524158887639079520012193273126047859425087639153757049236500533455762536198787501905199875019052100
```

**Reference**

- [GNU MP Homepage](https://gmplib.org/)
- [GNU MP Manual](https://gmplib.org/manual)
- [Tutorial on GMP](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

A `long long int` or an `int64_t` will suffice for a 64 bit integer. However, the max 64 bit integer is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, while your number is bigger than that, thus a 128-bit integer could be used, but still I am afraid this will not be enough.

GCC does have an `uint128_t`/`int128_t` type, starting from version 4. Read more in [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc)

Comment: @MarkDong your number is bigger than 64 bits can hold, see my improved answer!