# How to use modulo when denominator is out of unsigned long long int bounds?

Tags: c++, modulo

Given 1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>18</sup> and 1 ≤ K ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>, how do I do the operation N % K<sup>2</sup>? The K<sup>2</sup> (Denominator) goes out of bounds for unsigned long long int when K is near the value 10<sup>18</sup>, so I cannot store the value K2.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & 
[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if **K<sup>2</sup>** is bigger than **N** then **N % K<sup>2</sup>** is equal to **N**.

Example:

> 253 % 17<sup>2</sup> = 253 % 289 = 253

Assuming 64-bit `unsigned long long`, the maximum value that can be squared without overflow is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 which is equal to 0xFFFFFFFF (or 4'294'967'295).

Thus you can simply have the following code:

```
unsigned long long compute(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k)
{
    if (k > 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
        // k² is bigger than n (require more than 64 bits), so the modulo is n
        return n;
    }

     return n % (k * k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a bigint library because

- if K > 10<sup>9</sup> then K<sup>2</sup> > 10<sup>18</sup> > N, hence N % K<sup>2</sup> = N. No need to calculate K<sup>2</sup>
- if K ⩽ 10<sup>9</sup> then you can calculate `N % (K*K)` using the normal `uint64_t` without overflow

FWIW there's also a 128-bit type in most modern compilers in 64-bit mode. GCC, Clang and ICC call it [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)

See [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16088282/995714)

Comment: Well you have to take the exact limit (as in my answer), otherwise you won't get the correct answer in some cases (for ex. if N is 5 × 10^18 and K is 2 × 10^9).

Comment: @Phil1970 the condition is that N ⩽ 10¹⁸ so what you said never happens