# Is it possible to create a custom sized variable type in c?

Tags: c, types

Good evening, sorry in advance if I have a bad English, i'm French.

So, in C, there is different variable types, for example int, long, ... That takes a number of bytes depending of the type, and if I'm not wrong the "largest" type is long long int (or just long long) that takes 8 bytes of memory (like long which is weird so if someone could explain me that too thanks)

So my first question is: can I create my custom variable type that takes for example 16 bytes or am I forced to use strings if the number is too high for long long (or unsigned long long) ?

Comment: There are systems where `int` is 2 bytes, `long` is 4 bytes, and `long long` is 8 bytes. The C standard only puts a minimum size on each type. Implementations are free to use more bytes for a type, e.g. it's perfectly valid to use 8 bytes for a `long`, and 8 bytes for a `long long`.

Comment: You might already have [`uint128_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc) with 16 bytes. MSVC's `long` is 32-bit, the minimum size as it can be.

Comment: [Clang has new extended integer types with any number of bits from 1 to 16,777,215](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types) thanks to [Erich Keane at Intel](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html). Use `_ExtInt(N)` for the type, such as `_ExtInt(37) x;` to define a 37-bit integer named `x`.

Answer (score 9):

You can create custom types of all sorts, and if you want a "integer" type that is 16 bytes wide you could create a custom struct and pair two `long long`s together. But then you'd have to implement all the arithmetic on those types manually. This was quite common in the past when 16 bit (and even 32 bit) machines were most common, you'd have "bigint" libraries to do like 64-bit integer math. That's less useful now that most machines are either 64 bit or have `long long` support natively on 32 bit targets.

You used to see libraries with stuff like this quite often:

```
typedef struct _BigInt {
    unsigned long long high;
    unsigned long long low;
} BigInt;

// Arithmetic functions:

BigInt BigIntAdd(BigInt a, BigInt b);

// etc.
```

These have faded away somewhat because the current typical CPU register width is 64 bits, which allows for an enormous range of values, and unless you're working with very specialized data, it's not longer "common" in normal programming tasks to need values outside that range. As @datenwolf is explicit and correct about in the comments below, if you find the need for such functionality in production code, seek out a reliable and debugged library for it. (Writing your own could be a fun exercise, though this sort of thing is likely to be a bug farm if you try to just whip it up as a quick step along the way to other work.) As Eric P indicates in the comments above, [clang offers a native way of doing this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extended-integer-types) without a third party library.

(The weird ambiguities or equivalencies about the widths of `long` and `long long` are mostly historical, and if you didn't evolve with the platforms it's confusing and kind of unnecessary. See the comment on the question about this-- the C standard defines minimum sizes for the integer types but doesn't say they have to be different from each other; historically the types `char`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `long long` were often useful ways of distinguishing e.g. 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit sizes but it's a bit of a mess now and if you want a particular size modern platforms provide a `uint32_t` to guarantee size rather than using the "classic" C types.)

Comment: What do you mean by "pair two long long"?

Comment: @Fayeure I added an example of what that sort of thing would look like. You'd define a struct and then have to write the functions that would do the carries correctly, etc.

Comment: Okay, so when the first variable reaches long long max value we start adding the value we want to add in the second?

Comment: @Fayeure Yes, you would essentially create an abstraction layer like that. I should have named these high and low for the example, I'll edit it.

Comment: The problem is if I want to print the value how can I do that without involving strings? Because we can't add the first value to the second and then print it

Comment: @Fayeure: Essentially what you do is long addition / multiplication as you've learnt in school. Only that a digit doesn't go from 0…9 but from 0…2^64-1. When adding or multiplying you'll have to carry. Interestingly enough this is usually easier done with assembly than with C, since most CPU architectures offer a carry flag for doing exactly that. C doesn't give you access to that.

Comment: What @datenwolf said. :) Thank you for making that explicit.

Comment: "... *many platforms define* ..." -- `uint32_t` et al are defined by the C standard since 1999, and are in `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`. They may not exist if the implementation doesn't have types that meet the requirements (unlikely for typical systems). Also, `long long` is a signed type; for this kind of thing you'll want unsigned an type, at least for the low-order half.

Comment: @Fayeure: Printing numbers is actually more involved than it looks on the surface. If your number base is a power of two it's very easy, since you can just take the n lowest bits, use those as index into the digit array, shift n to the left, rinse & repeat until  no more nonzero bits are left. For bases other than 2^n you're doing a divide by base, print the remainder and rinse repeat that on the division result until it's zero. Division is somewhat expensive though and you'll have to do it in long form.

Comment: As far as bignums or arbitrary precision numbers go: For any practical situation I suggest to just grab a well tested library for that, that offers all the arithmetic primitives and string formatting and reading and call it a day. – Doing this by yourself is a great learning exercise, but I thoroughly recommend against it, if you need this to work reliably in your projects.

Comment: @KeithThompson: touché, and thanks. Updated for both unsigned and availability of uint32_t. (My aging self rarely remembers that what feel like new niceties are actually standardized beyond my environment. Thanks for the context.)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can. By preference you should not use string, because computations with those will be a lot more complicated and slower.

Also, you may not want to use bytes, but the 2nd largest datatype available on your compiler, because detecting overflow can be cumbersome if you're using the largest datatype.