# How to sequentially generate bytes in C?

Tags: c, byte

Given the example code below that generates 32 bytes and masks the first bytes with zeroes.

```
 static uint256_t rand256(struct seed *seed)
{
    seed->counter++;
    return sha256(seed, sizeof(struct seed));
}

static uint256_t rand256_and_mask(struct seed *seed)
{
    uint256_t r = rand256(seed);
    memset(&r, 0, 27);
    //r.i8[23] = 0xE;
    return r;
}
```

I would like to get the bytes sequentially(as in sequence like `\x09,\x0A ... 99`) with the difference of `+1`, like if the last byte is `"\x09"` on first call then on second call it would be `"\x0A"`.

Note: the numbers i am working on are very large and my program accept type `"uint256_t"` which is declared like this:

```
union uint256_s
{

    uint8_t i8[32];
    uint16_t i16[16];
    uint32_t i32[8];
    uint64_t i64[4];
};
typedef union uint256_s uint256_t;
```

Lets say uint256_t r = rand256(seed); produce this on first execution of my program:

```
E8411A8777E440FD1FA6CBF5F5149D14B45844B32F7B720CE653686229F9B758
```

then after memset in rand256_and_mask() the value of `r` returned will be:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029F9B758
```

Here i need to keep the value of `r` which i will then increment by 1 on the next call (skip rand256() call if necessary), so the value of `r` will be:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029F9B759
```

Technically i need the program to keep track of `r` as it represents a position in range.
I am not fluent in C, so I hope I clarified something.

C developers please help.

Comment: If I get you right, you are basically trying to keep a `uint256_t` counter that you can return on each function call and that you need to increment by 1. correct?

Comment: @Gerhardh Thats correct

Comment: Is that your own type to hold 256 bits or are you using a library providing that type? Does it also provide functions to to arithmetic operations on it? If not, you may add 1 like you would add it with pen and paper for normal numbers. Sum up each digit, check if you need to carry over to next digit, repeat...

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. You have the `uint256_t` type, but as the very first thing mask off 28 bytes so you are essentially left with an `uint32_t`. What keeps you from working with a `uint32_t` from that point on? i.e. `static uint32_t rand256_and_mask(struct seed *seed) { return rand256(seed).i32[7]; }`.

Comment: @nielsen the masking is just zfill because the program will expects 1 to 256 bit in 256 bit form

Comment: `uint256_t` is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p2).  Which means using it [invokes undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3p2).  Not likely to cause problems?  [128-bit numbers have already been around for over 10 years....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memset` to set all its bytes to 0. To sequentially generate bytes in C, you can modify the provided code as follows:

```
static int currentNumber = 9; // store current

static uint256_t getNextNumber()
{
    currentNumber++;
    if (currentNumber > 99)
        currentNumber = 10;

    uint256_t result;
    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(uint256_t));

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result.i8[i] = currentNumber & 0xFF;
        currentNumber >>= 8;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Each time you call the `getNextNumber` function, it will generate the next sequential byte pattern based on the `currentNumber`.

Comment: The use of `memset` is rather pointless if you immediately fill all the bytes afterwards. And an `int` variable will barely provide enough bits to fill a `uint256_t`

Comment: This seems like an odd answer to an admittedly very weird question. Given that `currentNumber` is always `<= 99`, why the loop? Looks like something CharGPT would come up with.

Comment: you may have misunderstood me, 10 to 99 is a sample range in which numbers are extracted sequentially, as from 10 to 99 but that is just a gist of what i am trying to achieve because i need to do that with the earlier code, with bytes not integers, let me update the question to claarify

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to increment an array of `uint8_t` in big-endian byte order:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

```
void incu8v(uint8_t *v, size_t len)
{
    while (len-- > 0)
    {
        if (++v[len] != 0)
        {
            /* No carry. */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This function will increment one of your `uint256_t` in-place (pass a pointer to the `uint256_t`):

```
void inc256p(uint256_t *v)
{
    incu8v(v->i8, sizeof(v->i8));
}
```

This function will increment a `uint256_t` by value and return the incremented value:

```
uint256_t inc256(uint256_t v)
{
    inc256p(&v);
    return v;
}
```

The way the `i16`, `i32` and `i64` member values are changed will depend on the native byte order of your machine.

`inc256()` and `inc256p()` do not mask the result, but `incu8v()` can be used to increment a subsequence of the bytes in place, e.g.

```
incu8v(r.i8 + 27, 5);
```

---

Note that identifiers that begin with `int` or `uint` and end with `_t` are reserved by the C standard, so the type name `uint256_t` should be renamed to something that is not reserved.