# How to load uint8_t "as" 32 bits integer efficiently into a SIMD register?

Tags: c++, simd, avx512

I have an array of 8 bit integers that I want to process through SIMD instructions.
Since those integers will be used along single precision floating point numbers, I actually want to load them in 32 bit lanes instead of the more "natural" 8 bit lanes.

Assuming AVX512, if I have the following array:

```cpp
std::array< std::uint8_t, 16 > i{ i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13, i14, i15 };
```

I wish to end up with a `__m512i` register filled with the following bytes:

```
[ 0, 0, 0, i0,
    0, 0, 0, i2,
    0, 0, 0, i3,
    0, 0, 0, i4,
    0, 0, 0, i5,
    0, 0, 0, i6,
    0, 0, 0, i7,
    0, 0, 0, i8,
    0, 0, 0, i9,
    0, 0, 0, i10,
    0, 0, 0, i11,
    0, 0, 0, i12,
    0, 0, 0, i13,
    0, 0, 0, i14,
    0, 0, 0, i15 ]
```

What is the best way to achieve that? I currently handroll it using:

```
_mm512_set_epi32(
    a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3],
    a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7],
    a[8], a[9], a[10], a[11],
    a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15]);
```

Note: I used AVX512 as an example, ideally I would like a "generic" strategy that can be abstracted on several instruction sets using e.g. Google Highway.

Comment: Check [Boost multiprecision](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) it uses compiler specific unsigned [int128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc)  you looking for.

Comment: Your title is asking for i8 input, but you're actually zero-extending it like u8, not sign-extending.

Comment: Exactly @PeterCordes, in my use case the integers are unsigned. If only using google highway I think I can get away with loading a full vector of u8 then promoting it to a same size vector of u32 (Highway will take care of the zero extension - even sign extension if my integer would be signed - if I'm not mistaken). I'm still working on it so I won't answer or edit my own question right now.

Comment: Well that's why I fixed your title to `uint8_t` instead of `int8`, because that's the difference between `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32` and `_mm512_cvtepi8_epi32`.  Your original title was consistent with a different answer than your question body.  In this case x86 with SSE4.1 or later, and I think ARM NEON/ASIMD, can widen with zero or sign extension fairly easily, but it's not generally true that signed and unsigned have equivalent answers.

Comment: Restricting to AVX512, I can do a masked load using `_mm512_mask_loadu_epi32` with the proper cast, then convert the register using `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this using Google Highway.

```
#include <hwy/highway.h>

namespace hn = hwy::HWY_NAMESPACE;

namespace ns::HWY_NAMESPACE {

template< typename FD, std::integral I >
    requires(std::floating_point< hn::TFromD< FD > > &&
        sizeof(I) <= sizeof(hn::TFromD< FD >))
auto loadAsFp(FD fd, const std::span< const I >& data)
{
    using FP = hn::TFromD< FD >; // The target floating point type.
    // A tag to select the proper vector type to load:
    // It will have the same number of lanes as the vector of FP modeled by the tag FD.
    // If it is not a full vector, highway will emulate as best as it can.
    using ID = hn::Rebind< I, FD >;
    auto ld = hn::LoadU(ID{}, data.data());
    if constexpr (sizeof(I) < sizeof(FP))
    {
        // If the integer type is strictly smaller than the target floating type, we must first do a promotion.
        // Note we target a signed type regardless:
        // Highway will be smart enough to figure out if it can ZeroExtend instead of SignExtend.
        using PromotedD = hn::Rebind< hwy::MakeSigned< hn::TFromD< FD > >, FD >;
        return hn::ConvertTo(fd, hn::PromoteTo(PromotedD{}, ld));

    }
    else
       return hn::ConvertTo(fd, ld);
}

} // ns::HWY_NAMESPACE
```

Then you get the plumbing and compile this for the desired targets. Assuming we compiled for AVX512, this could be used as follows:

```
const std::vector< std::uint8_t > is{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

auto vec = ns::N_AVX3::loadAsFp(hwy::N_AVX3::ScalableTag< float >{}, std::span{is});
```

For AVX512, this is equivalent to:

```
auto ld = _mm512_cvtepi32_ps(
    _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(
        _mm_loadu_epi8(is.data())));
```

Answer (score 4):

Load them in a register as a contiguous array `_mm_loadu_si128`, use `reinterpret_cast` or c-style cast, notice load**u** for unaligned. Then expand using `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32`.

The usual obstacle in populating AVX-512 register with smaller vector is the lack of cross-lanes instructions (in particular, lack of cross-lane `pshufb` equivalent), but for this particular tasks the above mentioned intrinsic is a perfect match.

Comment: You don't have to first convert to `epi16` you can directly use `__m512i _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i a)`

Comment: *Load them in a register* - nope, in asm you want the compiler to fold that load into a memory source operand for `vpmovzxbd zmm0, [rdi]`.  Only with C/C++ intrinsics do you have to write it as a `_mm_loadu_si128` into a `__m128i` vector variable.  You want that `__m128i` variable optimized away entirely, not to be a register in asm.  (On Intel CPUs, a destination of 256-bit or wider means it can't micro-fuse so it's still 2 total uops for the front-end, but smaller machine-code.)

Comment: *lack of cross-lanes instructions* - AVX-512VBMI in Ice Lake fixed that problem: lane-crossing `vpermb` is single-uop with 3c latency.  https://uops.info/ / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#BW,_DQ_and_VBMI (`vpermt2b` is still multiple uops, and unfortunately the backwards-compatible AVX512F `vpermw` and `vpermt2w` are still multiple uops, so you can't write code that's compatible with old CPUs but fast on new CPUs.)

Comment: If you had to emulate `vpmovzxbd` in terms of other instructions, you might do a 128-bit broadcast-load (`VBROADCASTI32X4 ZMM, M128` - no ALU uop) and `vpshufb` with a control vector, with actually lower latency I think since the ALU uop is only 1c vs. 3 for the lane-crossing `vpmovzxbd`!  Or `vpermw` and a zero-masked `vpmultishiftqb` if you're feeling creative and don't mind setting up 2 vector constants and a mask register constant in a `k` register.

Comment: Emulating sign-extension is harder than zero-extension, since upper bytes need to be 0 or -1 depending on a bit of another byte.  Shuffling the bytes to the top of dwords and using an arithmetic right shift could work if you needed to emulate for some reason (e.g. SSE2 or SSSE3 without SSE4.1)